# How to do hardware h.264 video encoding on android platform

Tags: android, video, h.264, encode, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to do hardware h.264 video encoding platform, I've learned that "MediaCodec" seems support hardware video decoding, but does it support hardware video encoding?

Some search results from google suggest I should consider search for different solutions for different chips according to user's Android device, does this mean I should go to each chip provider's website to search for different solution?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MediaCodec class also supports video encoding. The MediaCodec class was explicitly designed for multi device hardware accelerated media processing so that the same code runs on every device (from experience i can tell you it won't)

Good readings about this topic: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html
http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Remember, MediaCodec min-sdk version is 16 (i recommend to target api 18 e.g. usage of surface / MediaMuxer class), so if you're targeting devices with api < 16 MediaCodec won't do. If you wan't to target these devices you'll have to use lib stagefright and OpenMax wich i do not recomend